# Self instantiate inside static javascript class method a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Is this a bad code using OOP JS(this is TS)?

```
class KYC {
 public reference;
 public data = null;

 constructor(id: string) {
   this.reference = id? firestoreAdmin.collection('kyc').doc(id) :
           firestoreAdmin.collection('kyc').doc() :
 }

 async get() {
  const result = await this.reference.get();

  if(!result.exist) throw new Error('not found');

  this.data = result.data;

  return this;
 }

 static async getById(id: string) {
  return await new this(id: string).get();
 }
}
```

I wrote it like that because I find using **new Kyc(id).get();** to be somewhat unreadable inside an express.

also a question is this a bad practice in some way? anti - pattern?

any opinions would be great!

Comment: Questions about working code can be interesting, but they are a better fit at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than Stack Overflow

Comment: Hmm, you are immediatelly throwing an instance away after creation. `getById` would return a promise that would be resolved to `undefined` (or get rejected). Making newly created instance inaccessible. How do you plan to use `getById`?

Comment: Well, not immediatelly but until the promise got settled :) but hope you got the idea. The instance is not accessible :)

Comment: @NinoFiliu, ohhh, thanks! sure i'll ask it there

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, sorry I forgot to put async/await

Comment: @Reyn You'd still need to have something like this `static async getById(id: string) {
  const instance = new this(id: string); await instance.get(); return instance;
 }` or make get method to follow fluent interface by adding `return this` in the end.

Comment: also @YuryTarabanko, what site can you suggest as to where can I improve or make some best practices in regards to this?

Comment: I'd suggest to rename method to `createById` since it (eventually) creates a new instance on every call. Other than that it looks ok.

Comment: yeah,  aside from that, is my updated code an anti pattern of some sort?

or does it look horrible?

what are some best practices in going OOP via javascript?

Comment: What is the point of this class? To me this looks like a function.

Comment: @Reyn Speaking of OOP. As Thomas I don't see the point of this class. This looks like a single function to me.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ahh yes, I used it as a class I am sure that it would get bloated soon enough enough once, I implement the full CRUD of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is self-instantiation inside static class method a bad practice?

No, not at all. It's totally fine to use a static method as a factory.

The weird thing in your code is that you are initialising `data` asynchronously. That might be on purpose, but from my perspective the class is pretty useless without the data, so I would suggest to do that up front, inside the static method:

```
class KYC {
  constructor(
    public reference,
    public data,
  ) {}

  static async getFromReference(reference) {
    const result = await reference.get();
    if (!result.exist) throw new Error('not found');
    return result.data;
  }
  static async getById(id: string) {
    const reference = firestoreAdmin.collection('kyc').doc(id);
    return new this(reference, await this.getFromReference(reference));
  }

  … // further methods operating on this.data
}
```

Comment: I did it as I am using `firebase-admin`. it fetches from a collection from a database. so thats why data is there also, after fetching it will be populated from its initial result